About how to calculate observables in Quantum Monte Carlo with complex weights
I'm rewriting a Diagrammatic Quantum Monte Carlo algorithm following Werner, P., Oka, T., & Millis, A. J. (2009). Diagrammatic Monte Carlo simulation of nonequilibrium systems. Physical Review B, 79(3), 035320.
In this framework my configurations have complex weights $w(c)=\phi_c|w(c)|$, in general I understood that to obtain the average of a certain observable I should considerate the following
$$\langle O\rangle = \frac{\sum_c O(c)w(c)}{\sum_c w(c)} = \frac{\sum_c O(c)\phi_c|w(c)|}{\sum_c\phi_c|w(c)|} = \frac{\sum_c O(c)\phi_c|w(c)|}{\sum_c\phi_c|w(c)|} \frac{\sum_c|w(c)|}{\sum_c|w(c)|} = \frac{\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}{\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}$$
At this point I have a problem, how can $\langle O \rangle$ be a real quantity? Actually my observable is like a Kronecker delta i.e. is $1$ if some condition is met and $0$ otherwise. So the value of $\langle O \rangle$ (calculated as the fraction between the two averages with respect to the absolute value of the configurational weight) is given by the sum of all the complex phases at the denominator and the sum of some of the complex phases at the numerator. This is not a real quantity at all. How can I pratically calculate $\frac{\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}{\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}$ and obtain a real valued $\langle O \rangle$ via the Monte Carlo algorithm? Should I take the real part? The module? Maybe it is obvious, but I really don't know which is the correct thing to do and can't find anything anywhere. Thanks for helping

Link to abstract page?

https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.79.035320                       https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2345

Also consider to spell out acronyms.

Disclaimer: I have never done MC with complex weights so you might not want to put overly much trust in my answer.
Your formula seems correct to me. If I where in your situation I would ask myself 2 questions:

Can I derive from some physical or analytical consideration that the expectation value of my observable has to be real?
Can I derive from some physical or analytical consideration that the expectation value of the phase has to be real?

If both is the case I would conclude that all the complex contributions to the expectation value should cancel out and any remaining complex contribution, would have to be an artifact of the statistical uncertainty of the simulation and that to be the case for $\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}$, $\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}$ and $\langle O\rangle $ seperatly. It would then seem reasonable to just consider the real part of both your observable and average phase $\langle O\rangle = \frac{Re(\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})}{Re(\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})}$ and scale your error estimate accordingly.
Always doubting I would then think about the other intuitive options and find that, if O is a real observable, in the limit of infinite samples one would expect, that $\langle O\rangle = \frac{Re(\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})}{Re(\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})} = Re\left(\frac{\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}{\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}\right) = \left|\frac{\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}{\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}\right|$. If the average phase is also known to be real I would choose $\frac{Re(\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})}{Re(\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})}$ as it does contain the most known background information of our system.
If one does not know that the average phase should be real, the 3 above expression should still hold in high samples size limit however then $Re\left(\frac{\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}{\langle\phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|}}\right)$ seems to be the more intuitive choice.
Being rigorous one would now have to think deeply about, what kind of systematic errors could be introduced in each of the expression due to the statistical fluctuations in the denominator. However as a dirty-numerics-guy-workaround I would perhaps just argue that either in a well converged case all 3 of the expression should yield very similar values and just check if they lie within my error estimate or the simulation results will probably be flawed with such a strong sign problem, that they might be practically useless anyways.
Sorry for the handwavy answer, but since I suspect there might be not overly many people here being interested in the topic of your question I thought I would just give it a try.

Thanks a lot for your kind answer! I'm doing this tests you suggested. I also have found some info in  here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332750845_Exact_real-time_dynamics_of_single-impurity_Anderson_model_from_a_single-spin_hybridization-expansion. I cite, "... For each diagram having operators on the real branch there exists another which has exactly the same weight but the opposite sign ... This means that the average complex sign is real quantity which equals the probability of having no operators on real-time branches ... the average sign decreases exponentially with tmax ..."

This convinces me that I should choose the $\langle O\rangle = \frac{Re(\langle O\phi_c\rangle_{|w_c|})}{Re(\langle \phi_c\rangle_{|w_c|})}$ approach. But I also should probably use more data to obtain the average values to get a stable real valued mean phase value. The values of my tmax should not have problems because are to ones from the Werner et all article, so maybe it's only a matter of how many data I take? I hope so. Thank you a lot again!

I write here the solution that worked for me, at which I arrived with the help of the user that answered previously and this reference "Exact real-time dynamics of single-impurity Anderson model from a single-spin hybridization-expansion" by P. Kubiczek et al. (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332750845_Exact_real-time_dynamics_of_single-impurity_Anderson_model_from_a_single-spin_hybridization-expansion).
I cite from Kubiczek et al. pag 7

However, the presence of real-time branches causes the dynamical sign problem. For each diagram having operators on the real branch there exists another one which has exactly the same weight but the opposite sign. This results from the fact that operator closest to tmax on the real axis can be moved freely from the upper to the lower branch (or conversely) and
this operation changes only the sign of the diagram. This means that the average complex sign $\langle sgn \rangle$ is a real quantity which equals the probability of having no operators on real-time branches.

This does not say anything about what to do, but makes me think that the correct option should be
$$\langle O \rangle = \frac{\text{Re}(\langle \phi_c O\rangle_{|w(c)|})}{\text{Re}(\langle \phi_c\rangle_{|w(c)|})}\simeq \frac{\sum_{\text{MC config}}\text{Re}(\phi_{\text{MC config}} O)}{\sum_{\text{MC config}}\text{Re}(\phi_{\text{MC config}})}$$
Because one expect the average complex sign to be real.
